# Picking $r$ elements from two sets

Tags: combinatorics

Given two set $A_n$, and $B_m$. Pick $k$ elements from $A_n$ and pick $(r-k)$ elements from $B_m$. Where $r$ is given constant, and $k$ varies $0 \to r$.

This gives the following equivalence:

$$\sum_{k=0}^r \binom n k \binom m {r-k} = \binom {m+n} r$$

This conclusion is quite instinct: "picking from separate sets" is equal to "picking from united set". It is (maybe) too instinct to find a mathematically proof.

So my question is: Is there a formal proof of this theory?

---

I have a textbook says:

> Consider first choose $k$ elements from $A_n$ gives $\binom n k$, then choose $(r-k)$ from $B_m$ gives $\binom m {r-k}$. Combined there are $\binom n k \binom m {r-k}$. From Rule of Sum there are total $\binom {n+m} r$ ways.

, which I think it can't be a serious proof.

Comment: Tweak $r$ to $n$ gives another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004976/number-of-ways-to-pick-an-equal-number-of-elements-from-two-sets . This is answered but also not-proved.

Comment: What do you mean by "intrinct"?  You can write $S\cap(A\cup B)=(S\cap A)\cup(S\cap B)$ to justify the proof, but I don't see that it makes it any clearer.

Comment: @saulspatz Take the textbook as instance. 'From Rule of Sum' is vague, like hopping directly from LHS to RHS.

Comment: You didn't answer the question what you mean by "intrinct". That's not a word in English.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, "instinct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

---

What you gave is a combinatorial proof, but the Wikipedia link also gives an algebraic proof involving the power series of binomials to a power. Specifically, the relationship between the left and right side is an examination of the coefficients of:

$$
(1+x)^n(1+x)^m = (1+x)^{n+m}
$$

When you multiply two power series together, the sequence of coefficients of the resulting power series is a Cauchy product of the sequence of coefficients of the two factor series. Or to put it more simply, expand each of these using the binomial theorem and distribute.

The geometric proof given is basically a grid-walking combinatorial proof.

Comment: From here I learned: 1. This is named Vandermonde's Identity; 2. The combinatorial proof use a thing named "double counting proof", not just palely "from Rule of Sum". These are what textbook didn't tell me. Thank for your help.